# Keeping random numbers the same after refresh, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, reload

I am creating a multiple choice generator that can generate multiple choice answers based on input data. The random number generators are in the page's controller. The controller gets called during a refresh and as such, the random numbers change.

I thought of storing the random numbers in sessions. But this would cause all the random numbers to stay the same even when I do want to change my input data (such as loading a new page).

Is there a way to block the controller action during page refreshes? Or another easy way to have the random numbers stay the same on page refresh, but change when loading new page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood, you want:

- IF page reloaded, the random number would stay the same on the page
- ELSE if changed / new page, the random number would be regenerated

Then you could do something like:

**your_controller.rb:**

```
before_action :set_random_number, only: [:index]

def set_random_number
  message_encryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)

  # if no random number yet for this page, then generate, then redirect to same page but now with random_number param
  if params[:random_number].blank?
    # we need to encrypt the random_number so that user won't be able to manipulate the value in the query params
    encrypted_random_number = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(
      message_encryptor.encrypt_and_sign(
        some_code_of_yours_that_generates_the_random_number
      )
    )
    redirect_to request.query_parameters.merge(random_number: encrypted_random_number)

  else
    @random_number = message_encryptor.decrypt_and_verify(
      Base64.urlsafe_decode64(params[:random_number])
    )
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb:**

```
<%= @random_number %>
```

Comment: If you are getting `ArgumentError (key must be 32 bytes)`, try checking out the following and see if it helps: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25185

Answer (score 0):

I think cookies are good idea for your problem, try this as an example, in your controller:

```
def index
  cookies[:number] ||= SecureRandom.hex(4)
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= cookies[:number] %>
```

Does that do what you want?

Comment: cookies would work, but wouldn't the numbers stay the same as I change pages as well? So the next question would have the exact same random numbers? Since it's a question show method so as I view different questions, wouldn't the numbers stay the same?

Comment: @RailroadTycoon you can also use session to store it.

Comment: @RailroadTycoon isn't your question exactly "Keeping random numbers the same after refresh" sorry, not sure I understand what you want to do.